# sqlite3 inner join comparing all columns

Tags: sqlite, inner-join

I have a sqlite database which contains two tables t1, t2 with the same schema. The tables consist multiple columns c1, c2, .., cn (more than 50).
I am trying to find the entires that are present and identical in both tables.
The issue I encounter is to compare all columns at once. Obviously, I don't want to compare every column explicitly. An example for two tables:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
AND t1.c2 = t2.c2
...
AND t1.cn = t2.cn
```

I could generate this huge query using python's sqlite3 module i guess, but i wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [compound SELECT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound), all columns in the subqueries are compared:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sqlite should support `NATURAL JOIN`, which joins by all "matching" columns by default.

```
SELECT
t1.*
FROM t1
NATURAL JOIN t2
```